# How to continue with the instalation of the following packages after an error?

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I need to install several dependencies that are contained in a file as follows:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
asgiref==1.0.0
attrs==16.3.0
autobahn==0.17.2
Automat==0.5.0
Beaker==1.8.1
bleach==2.0.0
boto==2.46.1
boto3==1.4.4
botocore==1.5.26
channels==1.0.3
chardet==2.3.0
click==6.7
constantly==15.1.0
cssselect==1.0.1
cupshelpers==1.0
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.25.2
daphne==1.0.3
decorator==4.0.11
```

I tried:

```
pip3 install -r list.txt
```

The problem is that this command is being broken after an error as follows :

```
  Downloading click-6.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (71kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 71kB 3.0MB/s 
Collecting constantly==15.1.0 (from -r list.txt (line 14))
  Downloading constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cssselect==1.0.1 (from -r list.txt (line 15))
  Downloading cssselect-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cupshelpers==1.0 (from -r list.txt (line 16))
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cupshelpers==1.0 (from -r list.txt (line 16)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cupshelpers==1.0 (from -r list.txt (line 16))
```

Since I need to install several dependencies, I would like to ignore these cases and to proceed with the installation of the missing dependencies, so I really would appreciate support to find this option,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xargs arguments solves the purpose for this. You can refer to this code:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read requirements_file; do
dependency ="$(echo "${requirements_file}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
if pip install "$dependency"; then
    echo "$dependency is installed correctly"
else
    echo "Could not install following dependency"
    fi
done < list.txt
```

This will try to install the dependency line by line, and in case of any failure, it will move to next dependency.